# What are hashes printed by cassandra-cli?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

What is the use of hashes which are printed when statements are executed by cassandra-cli?

```
    default@testkeyspace] create column family testcolumnfamily;
    5ec1d928-3ee5-11e0-b34a-e700f669bcfc
    Waiting for schema agreement...
    ... schemas agree across the cluster
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the UUID of the schema version that was created.  In old Cassandra versions, it helps disentangle things if multiple versions get established concurrently.